# Reloading a non-table view (iOS)

Tags: ios, xcode, image, ipad, reload

I'm working on a painting app, and I want to user to be able to switch through paintings that are saved as PNGs to the documents directory. I've made an IBAction that does this:

```
-(IBAction)switchPage:(id)sender{


if ([sender tag] ==1)
{

    currentImage=currentImage-1;

}
else
{

    currentImage++;


}
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:currentImage forKey:@"currentDoc"];

[self.view setNeedsDisplay];


}
```

Just to let you know, I have 2 buttons, a back and forward, and they're connected to the same IBAction that's pasted above. The back button has a tag of 1, and the forward button doesn't have a tag. `currentImage` is an int that is used to set an image's name, so if `currentImage` =1, then it would set the image to image1. But that's not what I'm having trouble with, I'm having trouble "reloading" the view. I'm using setNeedsDisplay, but it's not working, and I know that reloadData is only for UITables, so what else could I use?

I've been searching for an answer, but none of the existing questions about this don't have a clear answer, or are under different circumstances.

Thanks for your time and/or dealing with a stupid question, as I'm new to Xcode.

-Karl

Comment: Usually, the syntax for setNeedsDisplay is `[self.view setNeedsDisplay:YES];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see no view code in your post.

Assuming you have a UIImageView that is displaying the image you would just do:

```
myImageView.image = whateverUIImage;
```